# Activity launches transparent Overlay Activity. How to pass Data without closing the Overlay?

Tags: android, android-activity

in my app i am having an Activity that launches another Activity ontop of it. The second Activity is meant to provide controls like next and previous for the first activity.
How can i pass button events between the two activities that are visible at the same time without closing the Activity with the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send `Broadcast` in order to communicate between Activities.

In parent Activity register [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), then send a `Broadcast` by calling `sendBroadcast(..)` in child Activity.

Comment: would i have to register the reciever inside my mother activity or is it a seperate service?

Comment: `registerReceiver(..)` is defined on `Context` which is base of all Activities. So - yes, you must register it on your mother activity.

Comment: thanks very much for that answer. it was exactly what i needed and very simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do doesn't require two activies, but rather additional view objects on the main activity that will be shown/hidden/removed/added as buttons on this activity are pressed.

If you need additional help, I would recommend elaborating on your original post.

Comment: you are right that i could achieve the same with a view inside my original activity. the reason i chose a new activity is that i plan to extend it with way more funktionality. i believe that an new activity can handle these extensions better.